# In need of a hint to prove this limit doesn't exist.

Tags: limits

The limit in question is $$\lim_{(x,y) \to (0,0)} \frac{x^7 +x^4 y +x^3 y}{x^6 +x^3 y +y^2}.$$

I've tried numerous paths but they all seem to point to $0$.

Any hint would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Comment: What about the path $y=x^3$?

Comment: (Or $y=-x^3$ for that matter...)

Comment: When x approaches 0 and y approaches 0, "maybe" one could assume that x=y, substituting x=y, you will get a function in 1 variable. This may simplify your proof.

Comment: Compare x=y to x=-y. You get different limits.